# How to save changes on associated models in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm running Ember Data 1.0.0 with Ember 1.3.0.

I have this data:

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 185588,
    "name": "USB MIDI Adapter",
    "images":["imageid1", "imageid2"....]
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "id": "imageid1",
      "url": "google.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "imageid2",
      "url": "google.com2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And these models:

```
App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
    url: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    images: DS.hasMany('Image') 
});
```

In my template I have an edit form to change the url on the associated images:

```
  <form {{action save on="submit"}}>
   {{input type="text" value=name}}

    {{#each images}}
    * {{input type="text" value=url}}<br>
    {{/each}}

   <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
```

The save action is:

```
save: function() {
  var product = this.modelFor('productEdit');
  product.save();
  this.transitionTo('product', product);
}
```

The problem is that the save action only saves the product (PUT product), but not the changed that's made to the image urls. The model binding works fine, when I change the url on images the gui is updated as it should, but the PUT is not sent as it should.

How do I save the image changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to call save on each record, call save on the recordarray(which will iterate and save), or you can override the serializer (`serializeIntoHash`) to inject the images into the save of the product.

```
records.forEach(function(record){
   if(record.get('isDirty')) record.save();
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example for one of the solutions? I'm new to Ember (data) and not sure how to do that :)

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand, I see no relations and nothing special about the save function. Can you please explain?

Comment: All you have to do is grab the the recordarray and call save.  In the second example i made a dog object with colors hasMany, then i hit save and 3 calls to the server are made with each color's info

Comment: Thank you, `product.get('images').save();` worked perfectly :) It did send a PUT on all of the images even though only one was changed, do you know if it's possible to only PUT the images that actually are changed?

Comment: yeah, you can iterate over the array and get the property isDirty (bool) (`record.get('isDirty')`) and decide whether or not you save based on that value

Comment: Added an example above

Comment: Thanks but where do I find the record array? I tried `products.get('images').forEach` but that's not it right? :)

Comment: that's correct, product.get('images').forEach(function(image){}), I see you wrote products, are you working with more than 1 product?

Comment: Sorry typo, but it's just a local variable so it shouldn't matter? This is my code. The "isDirty" does not work? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UweweHO/1/edit

Comment: it's a property, you should use a getter, image.get('isDirty')