# Ember/Rails: Modelling contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, modeling

I'm building an application with Ember and Rails which has a contact form for new customers with the following fields:

- email
- name
- phone
- subject
- message

The Rails backend has already models for customer and messages. The attributes `email`, `name` and `phone` are customer data and `subject` and `message` will be part of the messages model in Rails.

Now, I'm wondering how I should design the ember model since the data of the form has to be distributed to two different backend models. I'm thinking of:

1. Having a message and a customer model ready in Ember and trying to split the data somewhere in Ember and save to the corresponding models. (Seems complicated).
2. Creating a contact controller in Rails which receives data from a contact form model in Ember with exactly the submitted fields. The contact model in Rails sorts the incoming data out and saves it correspondingly to customer and message.

I would probably go for the second option since I'm more experienced in Rails then in Ember but I hope somebody could give me a hint what is the proper way to handle models which have no exact equivalent on the backend.

I'm wondering also if the Ember.store is holding redundant data if the same customer data is present in the customer/messages and the contact form model in Ember.

Comment: I believe the app should remain RESTful with actual resource endpoints, not virtual resource endpoints. You can save the model's associated records in Ember using forEach.

Comment: Any idea where to find some examples of this? I haven't been able to find any so far.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640505/how-to-save-changes-on-associated-models-in-ember-data

Comment: Also, I believe if you are using ```JSONAPIAdapter```, you can use ```push``` with the relationship data in the serialized object. I need to test these theories.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push